# How to pass the gcloud --no-cache flag to the Maven App Engine plugin?

Tags: java, maven, google-app-engine, deployment

Running in a Google App Engine deployment issue.
See [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77181996/gcloud-build-failure-error-failed-to-initialize-analyzer-no-such-object/77354911#77354911](https://stackoverflow.com)

Google App Engine deployments that used to work several months ago do not work any more with App Engine Standard / Java 17 / bundled APIs / Maven App Engine plugin 2.4.4 and 2.5.0 / gcloud 452.0.0.

Here's the Cloud Build error:

`Step #2 - "build": ERROR: failed to initialize analyzer: getting previous image: getting config file for image "eu.gcr.io/PROJECTID/app-engine-tmp/app/default/ttl-18h:latest": GET https://storage.googleapis.com/eu.artifacts.PROJECTID.appspot.com/containers/images/sha256:036aff03ac31731663e8aee494f16b733e1c56e31b329b9db470007802a361e7?access_token=REDACTED: unexpected status code 404 Not Found: NoSuchKeyThe specified key does not exist.No such object: eu.artifacts.PROJECTID.appspot.com/containers/images/sha256:036aff03ac31731663e8aee494f16b733e1c56e31b329b9db470007802a361e7
Finished Step #2 - "build"
ERROR
ERROR: build step 2 "eu.gcr.io/gae-runtimes/buildpacks/google-gae-22/java/builder:java_20231016_RC00" failed: step exited with non-zero status: 1`

This question is related to [GCloud Build Failure: ERROR: failed to initialize analyzer, No such object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77181996/gcloud-build-failure-error-failed-to-initialize-analyzer-no-such-object/77354911#77354911)
This is why I would like to try to pass the gcloud --no-cache flag to the Maven App Engine plugin.

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/a/77244732/22796667 for a solution, i.e. migrating to Artifact Registry